# Repeating SQL Query takes long pause once or twice a minute

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have used the ADO-function from [another website](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm) to make a query from Excel VBA 2016 on my SQL Server Express database on the same workstation. The SQL database is continuously updated with new records from a feed provider.

The query runs very smoothly and takes around 70 milliseconds to execute. I call the query every 3 seconds from a routine in Excel VBA. Although once or twice a minute the query takes 6000-12000 milliseconds. It seems the query is "hanging" at these moments for some reason.

When I turn off the external feed, the issue is not there!

I also have used Express Profiler to get insight in the cause. I have added the output below this post. Lines 33 and 173 are lines with a long interval. As you can see this duration is much longer than the other (identical queries).

I have set the `READ_COMMIT_SNAPSHOT ON` in options.

I have also set `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON` in options.

I did not close down any connections, although SQL did give a message that it was closing all connections.

Although after testing the problem is still there.

After reading this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql I have tried using the command `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` but, after testing, the problem is still there.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: ps: is seems the output from Express Profiler is too long to add as comment and it is not lined well if I add it to my message.

Comment: If you care at all about accurate data DO NOT use read uncommitted. That is just like putting NOLOCK on every single query. There are many bad things that can happen here. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ What you are describing sounds like pretty typical lock escalation. Your read queries are unable to process because the external feed is inserting data which can cause a table lock. Why do you need to query this data every 3 seconds in the first place?

Comment: Thanks Sean. I can undo the uncommitted command although the problem is the same. I need it every 3 seconds since it is a live feed.

Comment: Why do you need to requery every 3 seconds? Sounds like you are doing this the hard way. You should check out signalr so you can push the data to your clients when the data changes instead of constantly beating up your sql server. There really isn't a way to improve this much when you are constantly running queries and inserts at the same time.

Comment: In general there is new data almost every 3 seconds. Would it make much difference in that case to use another method? Since the query takes only 70ms, i was quiet happy with it.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I have read https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/an-introduction-to-real-time-communication-with-signalr/  . Is this not more targetted at a situation with several web-based clients? I just have a database which has an external feed and i want to update this data in Excel.